# What is a Munger

Tags: class-design

I am reading the source code of ObjectListView and there is a Munger class. What is Munger? Does Munger mean anything general in programming jargon?

Afaik, the Munger in the source code wraps the methods to do map string to object properties through Reflection (C#).

Thanks.

Comment: Munge - colloquially (in Ireland anyway) - means forcing two (or more) things together that wouldn't normally fit, or fitting two (or more) things together poorly. Generally a solution involving _Munging_ is less than ideal.

Comment: if your solution involves munging it is probably minging

Comment: @Binary Worrier - That's what it means in the UK too, hence I might `munge together` data from several sources.

Comment: hmm.. I might have to re-read the soruce code to determine the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia [states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munged_password):

> In computing, the term munge means to attempt to create a strong,
>   secure password through character substitution. "Munge" is sometimes
>   backronymmed as Modify Until Not Guessed Easily.

Generally it means 'made unclear' or a bit mixed up when two or more elements have been transposed accidentally or deliberately.

Comment: The shorter version is "Mung" which is "Modify until no good". It is pronounced _Muhnj_.

Comment: What's difference between munging and obfuscation?

Comment: @Qix this finally explains to me the meaning of "Mung Demon" which was an enemy in the game Exile: Escape from the Pit.

Answer (score 3):

There is no **universal** definition for what 'munging' is.

It is usually used in the context of transforming data.

See [Wikipedia's "munge"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munge), [Wikipedia's "mung"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_%28computer_term%29), and [The Jargon File's "munge"](http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/munge.html) (which, in the context of the Munger.cs you are referring to, I would say that definition 1 - "to imperfectly transform information" is what was intended).

Answer (score 1):

As @Roger stated Munge has a specific meaning when obfusticating passwords. However it does have a more general (non) meaning and is to verbs what "widget" is to nouns.

i.e To Munge is "to perform some as yet unspecified action".

Therefore the OPs Munger will be used to perform an as yet unspecified method on some unknown object type. The exact method will only be chosen after examining the available methods from the object.

Comment: not quite, I think munging caries some negative connotations that widget doesn't